# ROI handles dont change their position while/after dragging

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, roi

heyho

#### situation

i have multiple scatterplots in a viewbox in pyqtgraph. since i want to 'cut something out' of it, i create a [PolyLineROI](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/graphicsItems/roi.html#pyqtgraph.PolyLineROI) somewhere in the plot with initial three handles. when i start dragging the whole thing to its destination (and append maybe append another handle) the positions of the handles still have their original position from where it started. even when i drag the handles themselves they change their values relativ to their starting position... which results in the wrong selected area.

#### MWE

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

def roiMove():
    """Print the coordinates of the ROI."""
    print(roi.getState()['points'])

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
vb = win.addViewBox()
# roi in rectangle shape
roi = pg.PolyLineROI([[1, 2], [1.5, 2], [1, 0]],
    closed=True,
    pen=pg.mkPen(color=(0, 201, 255, 255), width=3)
    )

# connect to printing function when moving something
# NOTE: when dragging the whole ROI the positions won't be updated
roi.sigRegionChanged.connect(roiMove)
vb.addItem(roi)
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```

it would be awesome if someone had an idea :-)

cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer in the real world... instead of the state's points it was the SceneHandlePositions that needed be mapped to the parent:

### MWE

```
import pyqtgraph as pg

def roiMove():
    """Print the coordinates of the ROI."""
    pts = roi.getSceneHandlePositions()
    print([roi.mapSceneToParent(pt[1]) for pt in pts])

win = pg.GraphicsWindow()
vb = win.addViewBox()
# roi in triangle shape
roi = pg.PolyLineROI([[1, 2], [1.5, 2], [1, 0]],
            closed=True,
            pen=pg.mkPen(color=(0, 201, 255, 255), width=3)
                )

# connect to printing function when moving something
roi.sigRegionChanged.connect(roiMove)
vb.addItem(roi)
vb.setXRange(-5, 5)
vb.setYRange(-5, 5)
pg.QtGui.QApplication.exec_()
```